# Functional/ES6 way to detect differences between date intervals?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date-fns

I have a function that I am using to try and determine if a set of date segments meets a criteria.

I am using date-fns' `distanceInDays` function to return an integer value of the distance between the previous segment's end date and the current segment's start date.

`(current.startDate - previous.endDate)`

Problem is that the `reduce` function is giving me type errors.

```
type DateSegment = {startDate: string, endDate: string} // ISO 8601 timestamps


const isValid = (current: ResidentialAddress, history: Array<ResidentialAddress>): boolean => {
    if (!current || history.length === 0) return false;

    const currentDate = formatInTimeZone(new Date(), 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    // Convert current residence and residential history to segments.
    const segments: DateSegment[] = [
        { startDate: current.startDate, endDate: currentDate },
        ...history.map(x => ({ startDate: x.startDate, endDate: x.endDate }))
    ];
    // Sort them
    const sorted = segments.sort((a, b) => isSameOrBefore(a.startDate, b.startDate));

    const result = sorted.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) =>
        differenceInDays(new Date(currentValue.startDate), new Date(previousValue.endDate))),
        {endDate: currentDate}
    );
    console.log(result);
    return true;
};
```

NB: The current residence does not have an end date, so the current date is provided to it.

Comment: Do you know you need to return the accumulator in the `reduce` ? What does `differenceInDays` return ?

Comment: `differenceInDays` returns an integer for the number of days difference between the two dates.  I would like it to check if the difference is over one day, or if the previous iteration produced `true`. If it does, then return `true`.

This is so that if there are more than one day difference between dates, the function returns `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return an array of distances between intervals.

```
const distances = array.map((item, index: number) => {
    if (!array[index-1]) return
    return item.start - array[index-1].end
    }
)
```